# UART: Only receiving mess on RasberryPi when connected to a PIC18

Tags: pic, c, raspberry-pi, uart

I have a [**PIC**18**LF**27**J**53](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30009964C.pdf) running properly and I'm able to make an LED blink. FOSC is at 8MHz (which is confirmed through the LED).

Now, I want to make the PIC send some bytes to the RaspberryPi via UART (I'm using `minicom` to inspect `/dev/ttyAMA0` and have disabled both bluetooth and the serial console). I tried with both TX1 and remapped TX2 but I'm only receiving the same mess (`fààþæ`). I tried to invert the logic, but that didn't help and I'm receiving `~øxøxxøxþ` instead.

This is my code to setup the UART interface (with BRGH, 8-bit BRG @ 9600):

```
TXSTA2   = 0b10100110;
RCSTA2   = 0b00010000;
BAUDCON2 = 0b01000010;
// BR=FOSC/(16(n+1)) <=> n=FOSC/BR/16-1
n = (uint8_t)round(1.0 * CLOCKSPEED / BAUDRATE / 16.0) - 1;
SPBRG2 = n;
RCSTA2bits.SPEN = 1;
```

The formula outputs 51 for `CLOCKSPEED = 8MHz` and `BAUDRATE = 9600` which is the same as written in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30009964C.pdf) (page 343).

This is the code I use to send a string:

```
void putc(char c)
{
    while(TXSTA2bits.TRMT == 0);
    TXREG2 = c;
}
void puts(const char *str)
{
    const char *p;
    for (p = str; *p; p++)
        putc(*p);
}
```

Finally, I call it like this:

```
const char *str = "HELLO\r\n";
puts(str);
```

What can I do to make the RaspberryPi receive the correct characters?

**EDIT**: I just tried to print the character `U` (`01010101`) continously via UART. Minicom receives continously alternating the chars `f` (`01100110`) and `æ` (`11100110`). So I'd guess that there is an issue with the baud rate. How can I check this and find the error?

Comment: Default INTOSC frequency is 4 MHz. Show us your CONFIG register settings and system clock initialization code.

Comment: @BruceAbbott INTOSC is a 8MHz clock but it seems the derived FOSC is only 4MHz by default. I was using the default config of XC8, but setting `PLLDIV` to 2 and the `IRCF` bits to 7 it's now working without ugly workaround.

Comment: @BruceAbbott do you know whether the PLL will influence the value I have to use for `CLOCKSPEED` or will it always be calculated from `INTOSC` clock?

Comment: Examine the clock circuit on page 32 of the datasheet:- "FIGURE 3-1: PIC18F47J53 FAMILY CLOCK DIAGRAM". There are several different ways to set the system clock frequency. With OSCCON<1:0> = 00 (default value) the system clock comes from INTOSC postscaled by OSCCON<6:4>, and the PLL has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I connected the TX pin of the PIC to a GPIO input pin of my RaspberryPi and wrote a little program to monitor what's going on:

```
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    #define BLOCK_SIZE 256

    #define GPIO_IN(g)  *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
    #define GPIO_OUT(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) |=  (1<<(((g)%10)*3))

    #define GPIO_SET(g)  *(gpio+7)  = 1<<(g)
    #define GPIO_CLR(g)  *(gpio+10) = 1<<(g)
    #define GPIO_LEV(g) (*(gpio+13) >> (g)) & 0x1

    #define PIN 18

    int                mem_fd;
    void              *gpio_map;
    volatile uint32_t *gpio;

    unsigned long ellapsed(struct timespec last, struct timespec now)
    {
      unsigned long diff = now.tv_sec - last.tv_sec;
      diff *= 1e9;
      diff += now.tv_nsec - last.tv_nsec;
      return diff;
    }

    int main()
    {
      mem_fd = open("/dev/gpiomem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
      assert(mem_fd != -1);

      gpio_map = mmap(NULL, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, 0);
      assert(gpio_map != MAP_FAILED);
      gpio = (volatile uint32_t*)gpio_map;

      GPIO_IN(PIN);

      struct timespec last, now;
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, &last);
      char state = 1;
      while (1)
        {
          if ((state & 0x1) != (GPIO_LEV(PIN)))
            {
              clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, &now);
              printf("state changed from %d to %d after %f µsecs (= %f kHz)\n", state, GPIO_LEV(PIN), ellapsed(last, now)/1000.0, 1.0/(ellapsed(last,now)/1e9)/1e3);
              last = now;
              state = GPIO_LEV(PIN);
            }
        }
    }
```

The speed was about 207 µsec per bit. I looked up the [speed of uart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Asynchronous_Receiver_Transmitter) and found that this equals a baud rate of 4800, exactly half of what I expected. Dividing `n` through 2 gives me the correct baud rate, although I don't understand why this is needed, as neither the datasheet nor the internet tells about such behaviour.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's just conforming that the baud rate is half what you expected.

Comment: @BruceAbbott It is an ugly workaround but fixed my problem so I'd call it an answer. Still I don't know what causes the issue so if you know it please provide a better answer